# Triple Nested For Loop with specific output (java)

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop

I need to write some java using 3 "for" loops that outputs

122333444455555

22333444455555

333444455555

444455555

55555

The code I have so far:

```
public static void problemFour() {
      for(int i = 5; i >= 1; i--) {
         for(int a = 1; a <= i; a++) {
            for(int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
               System.out.print(a);
            }
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
```

This outputs

```
111112222333445
11111222233344
111112222333
111112222
11111
```

I've switched around a lot of combinations of ++'s --'s, <'s, >'s, 5's, and 1's.

I'm pretty stuck, if someone could point me in the right direction, that would be fantastic.

Comment: Great that you're learning that triple nested for loops with int i, int a, and int b are hard to troubleshoot. If you forced yourself to write descriptive variable names that might help you. Also if you replaced one of the fors by a method invocation you'd probably be on your way

Answer (score 5):

You made mistake in how the line starts and how many times a digit (here character) gets repeated. Fix it by:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {          // Each iteration for one line
    for(int a = i; a <= 5; a++) {      // starts with a for ith line
        for(int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {  // a times `a` digit
            System.out.print(a);
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

To **simply** your problem, first think about printing this pattern :

```
12345
2345
345
45
5
```

**Then extend it:**  in innermost loop put the code for repetition equal to digit times, using :

```
for(int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {  // a times `a` digit
     System.out.print(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the observation that number `1` is printed only once, `2` twice, `3` thrice, etc.

`firstValueInLine` keeps the number the line starts;
`number` is the number in line being printed;
`counter` just ensures that `number` is printed `number` times

```
    for (int firstValueInLine = 1; firstValueInLine <= 5; ++firstValueInLine) {
        for (int number = firstValueInLine; number <= 5; ++number) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < number; ++counter) {
                System.out.print(number);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following. It will work.

```
  public static void problemFour() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      for (int a = i; a <= 5; a++) {
        for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
          System.out.print(a);
        }
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
```

**Output:**

```
122333444455555
22333444455555
333444455555
444455555
55555
```

Answer (score 0):

Thing here is, use 1st for-loop for number of lines, 2nd for-loop for getting the number to print. 3rd for-loop to print the displaying number for the required amount.
What you've done is correct in opposite way. So  make your code reverse.

Try this

```
public static void problemFour() {
      for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
         for(int a = i; a <= 5; a++) {
             for(int b=0;b<a;b++){
               System.out.print(a);  
             }                
         }
         System.out.println();
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the inline comments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 5, j = 1; i >= 1; i--, j++) { // Introduce a new variable j 
        for (int a = j; a <= 5; a++) { // change a=1 to a=j & a<=i to a<=5
            for (int b = 1; b <= a; b++) {
                System.out.print(a);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
122333444455555
22333444455555
333444455555
444455555
55555
```